# How can I carry JavaScript variables to subsequent functions?

Tags: javascript, function, math, discord.js, async.js

I'm writing a simple game in javascript running off of a discord bot. I'm having a little problem with variables not being carried over to subsequent functions. Module code:

```
module.exports = {
name: 'train',
description: "this is the single player training program vs ShounenB0t",
execute(message, args){
const student = message.author.id
const studentName = message.author.username
    message.channel.send(`${studentName} begin training!`);
    // fn to process the attack response
    PP = 0
    BP = 0
    waitForAttackInput(student);
    async function waitForAttackInput(student) {
    // prompt for attack input
    await message.channel.send(`${studentName} : Punch, kick, or block?`)
    const filter1 = m => m.author.id === student
    const collected = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter1, { max: 1 });
    const response = collected.first();
    if (response.author.id === student) {
        Move = response.content.toLowerCase();
        console.log(Move);
        if (Move === 'punch' || Move === 'kick' || Move === 'block') {
            rolldice()
            function rolldice() {
                BotDice1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((3 - 1) + 1) + 1);
                BotDice2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((20 - 1) + 1) + 1);
                StudentDice1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((20 - 1) + 1) + 1);
                }
                console.log(BotDice1);
                console.log(BotDice2);
                console.log(StudentDice1);
                
            //let BotMove;
            if (BotDice1 == 1){BotMove = 'punch'} 
            else if (BotDice1 == 2){BotMove = 'kick'} 
            else if (BotDice1 == 3){BotMove = 'block'};
                console.log(BotMove);
            if ((BotMove === 'punch' || Botmove === 'kick') && (Move === 'block')){
                if ((BotDice2 < 20 ) && (StudentDice1 == 20)){
                    message.channel.send(`${studentName} blocks PERFECTLY, and counterstrikes with an elbow strike to my solar plexus! Ouch! Point for ${studentName}!`);
                    PP = (PP + 1);
                    console.log(PP);
                    console.log(BP);
                    if (PP == 3) {
                        message.channel.send(`${studentName} wins the match!`)
                    }
                    else {waitForAttackInput(student);
                    }
                } else if (BotDice2 < StudentDice1){
                    message.channel.send(`${studentName}'s attack was blocked!`);
                    waitForAttackInput(student);
                } else if (BotDice2 > StudentDice1){
                    message.channel.send(`My attack got through your block! Point for me!`);
                    BP = (BP + 1);
                    console.log(PP);
                    console.log(BP);
                    if (BP == 3) {
                        message.channel.send(`I win the match!`);
                    }
                    else {waitForAttackInput(student);
                    }
                } else if (BotDice2 === StudentDice1){
                    message.channel.send('Oops, we both fell out of bounds. Return to centre. Fight!');
                    waitForAttackInput(student);
                }

            } else if ((Botmove === 'block') && (Move === 'punch' || Move === 'kick')){
                if ((BotDice2 == 20 ) && (StudentDice1 < 20)){
                    message.channel.send(`I block PERFECTLY, and I counterstrike with an elbow strike to ${studentName}'s solar plexus! Ouch! Point for me!`);
                    BP = (BP + 1);
                    console.log(PP);
                    console.log(BP);
                    if (BP == 3) {
                        message.channel.send(`I win the match!`)
                    }
                    else {waitForAttackInput(student);
                    }
                } else if (BotDice2 > StudentDice1){
                    message.channel.send(`${studentName}'s attack was blocked!`);
                    waitForAttackInput(student);
                } else if (BotDice2 < StudentDice1){
                    message.channel.send(`${studentName}'s attack got through my block! Point for ${StudentName}!`);
                    PP = (PP + 1);
                    console.log(PP);
                    console.log(BP);
                    if (PP == 3) {
                        message.channel.send(`I win the match!`);
                    }
                    else {waitForAttackInput(student);
                    }
                } else if (BotDice2 = StudentDice1){
                    message.channel.send('Oops, we both fell out of bounds. Return to centre. Fight!');
                    waitForAttackInput(student);
                }
            }
            else {
                message.channel.send('invalid move, please try again.');
                waitForAttackInput(student);
            }
        } 
    else {
        message.channel.send(`Another student already training!`);
        waitForAttackInput(student);
    }
    }
    }
```

According to my console logs, the correct values are showing up, but the variable is not being carried over to the next function, throwing an error at line 66 on BotMove:

```
Shounenb0t is online.
kick
1
5
15
punch
(node:9188) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: Botmove is not defined
    at waitForAttackInput (C:\DiscordB0ts\ShounenB0t\commands\train.js:66:24)       
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:9188) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, 
use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9188) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Given that *Botmove* has not been declared or otherwise initialised anywhere in the posted code, what did you expect? Or were you hoping for it to be created as a global in the sequence of `if (BotDice1..` blocks?

Comment: Yes, it is in the code.  It is defined via dice roll in the lines:
if (BotDice1 == 1){BotMove = 'punch'} 
            else if (BotDice1 == 2){BotMove = 'kick'} 
            else if (BotDice1 == 3){BotMove = 'block'};
The way the dice roll for this is designed, the roll can literally only be 1, 2, or 3.  Thus one of these 3 conditions will always be met, eliminating the need for an else at the end.  Also the console logs show that these dice rolls are being executed correctly and are even assigning the correct "move" to BotMove.  It just isn't getting carried over to the next function.